# Dynamically change font size in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-1.6-donut

I want to support font resizing with an entry in Preferences (where the user picks among given font size options) or by using a gesture (flinging up/down) as used in popular e-book reader applications such as [Aldiko](http://www.aldiko.com/). Flinging up and down along right side of the screen triggered brightness change in Aldiko.

How can I implement this type of dynamic property change?
Are there any implementation differences for this in 1.6 and 2.0+ ?
Do I have to have different themes pre-configured with different font sizes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, you do it like that:

```
TextView tv=new TextView(this);

    //either:
    tv.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.textStyle1); //some style you have set up


    ///or: 
    tv.setTextSize(16);
    tv.setTextColor(R.color.myred); //some color you set up
```

so not a static call to TextView you need an isntance of textview.

Comment: Okay, that one is trivial of course. However no such methods are available in Android 1.6. How can I achieve this in 1.6 ?

Comment: it works for 1.6 too http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html you can set filter by api level

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
```